# Ubuntu permissions to open files

Tags: permissions

My Macbook Pro hard drive is not working and I don't have a backup cd. I installed Ubuntu to see if I could access my files. I can see the folders but when I attempt to open them, I get a message that I do not have permission to view them. How can I get the required permission?

I tried <kbd>Right Click</kbd> >> <kbd>Properties</kbd> >> <kbd>Permissions</kbd> and the drop down menus are grey so I don't have the option to change them to read and write. Is there anything I can do to access the files?

Comment: did you use nautilus?

Comment: Linux only has read permissions for HFS file systems.

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal, and end enter the following command to get all permissions for nautilus:

```
gksu nautilus --no-desktop
```

This will open a new nautilus with the root user, which can read everything. The "--no-desktop" is needed because by default it would take over.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to this.  The vocabulary is totally unknown. How do I open a terminal?

Comment: open dash and start writing terminal OR press ctrl+alt+t

Comment: Ican view the files now but i cannot move them onto a usb stick.  It still says Error while copying file.  permission denied

Comment: i also attempted to change permissions and was not permitted

Comment: you cannot move them maybe because it is read only

Comment: you can copy only

Comment: i figured it out. when the document or picture is open - file-save as-wherever. Each file or picture individually. Took a long time but was able to save all my docs and pics on usb stick. Thanks for your help